# Output issues when working with structs in C++

Tags: c++, struct

We just started working with structs in class and were given pre-existing code and told to take user input for the struct and create a function which prints the inventory. This is what I have done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct LineItem
{
    int quantity;
    string description;
    double price;
};

void print_inventory_report(LineItem[],const int);


int main()
{
  const int arraysize = 2;
  LineItem inventory[arraysize];

  for(int index = 0;index < arraysize;index++)
  {
      cout << "What part is this for (enter a one word description)? ";
      cin >> inventory[arraysize].description;

      cout << "Enter the quantity: ";
      cin >> inventory[arraysize].quantity;

      cout << "Enter the price: ";
      cin >> inventory[arraysize].price;

      cout << endl;
  }

  print_inventory_report(inventory,arraysize);

return 0;
}

void print_inventory_report(LineItem inv[], const int s)
{
    cout << "Totals: " << endl;;

    for(int i = 0; i < s;i++)
        cout << "  " << i+1 << ". " << inv[i].description << " $" << (inv[i].quantity * inv[i].price) <<endl;
        cout << endl;
}
```

Based on this, if the user entered the following:

```
What part is this for? (Enter a one word description) Struts
Enter the quantity: 2
Enter the price: 45.68

What part is this for? (Enter a one word description) Oil
Enter the quantity: 4
Enter the price: 5.74
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
Totals:
  1. Struts: $91.36
  2. Oil: $22.96
```

But instead I get this:

```
Totals:
  1.   $7.95081e+070
  2.   $7.95081e+070
```

I also get the following error box:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpaJH.png)

Are the two problems I'm having connected to one another?

Comment: `inventory[arraysize]`  ->  `inventory[index]`

Comment: Oh @JamesRoot spotted it too, maybe I shouldn't have posted an answer!

Comment: @JamesRoot - Woooooowwww that was easy. I guess I've been staring at this too long. I must have tried a dozen corrections, just not that one :)

Comment: @gsamaras - Your answer is still appreciated. It was still informative! I thought I was looking at a memory address but I wasn't 100% sure, so you confirmed it for me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are the two problems I'm having connected to one another?

Yes, since you are actually accessing memory your program doesn't own! So, you output garbage values and you are getting a relevant error message. In Linux, I got:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras:~$ ./a.out 
What part is this for (enter a one word description)? Struts
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

---

You are doing:

```
const int arraysize = 2;
LineItem inventory[arraysize];
...
cin >> inventory[arraysize].description;
```

So now you trying to access an array *out of bounds*, since **indexing starts 
from 0**. A segmentation fault lurks.

---

You could use your counter and do:

```
cin >> inventory[index].description;
```

to get yourself ready for input. After correcting all the relevant errors in your code, you should be able to regenerate this behaviour:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras:~$ ./a.out 
What part is this for (enter a one word description)? Struts
Enter the quantity: 2
Enter the price: 3

What part is this for (enter a one word description)? Strats
Enter the quantity: 2
Enter the price: 3

Totals: 
  1. Struts $6
  2. Strats $6
```

---

You may want to have a look at my example [mystruct](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/structs-c/https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/structs-c/).